# Adding Sounds and Slowing Pronunciation for "Proper Speech"

Tags: pronunciation, accent, register

I routinely hear a relative add syllables to words to sound more "correct."  "menu" becomes "men-a-you." "Daily" becomes "day-uh-lee."  It seems to be coupled with a slowing of the pronunciation in imitation of a register of English "higher" than the casual Midwestern dialect. The subject is from Iowa and Minnesota, and has spoken German fluently, but English is the first language. What is this?

Comment: Pure speculation, but the speaker could be breaking unstable segments down into syllabic units. You'd need to show me more examples, but both [mɛ.nʌ.ju] and [de.jʌ.li] involve the syllabification of a sonorant which might be otherwise 'absorbed' into another segment, i.e. [mɛ̃.ju~mɛ̃ɲu], [deɪ̯.li]. If they're trying to speak 'more clearly', this syllabification might be a means the speaker is using to avoid the loss of underlying segments.

Answer (score 2):

There is the term **hypercorrection** for this kind of phenomena, although I am not sure if it is applicable to your example.

A typical example for hypercorrection is the following: A native speaker of the palatinate dialect (rheinfränkisch) does not discriminate the sounds /i/ and /y/ in dialectal pronunciation. So High German *kümmern* becomes *kimmern* in the dialect. Trying to speak High German, by analogy, forms like **schwümmen* for *schwimmen* come up.

Comment: This came to mind for me too, but I agree it could have another explanation — some phonotactic trouble in their idiolect...